# Vuforia black screen when creating 64 bit apk using Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, 64-bit, vuforia, il2cpp

As per the restrictions imposed by Google Play that only 64 bit apk are acceptable, I tried building my project using the **ARM64** **IL2CPP** setup for android apk in Unity.

Apk builds fine but when I run the app, I can't see the camera feed of the vuforia.

While my app works fine with 32 apk and I even have my 32 bit apk on play store.

I tried with different version of Unity like 2018.1,2018.2, 2018.4 but all have same issue.

Comment: What version of vuforia are you using? Have you tried googling it first?

Comment: @SaadAnees I have tried with vuforia 7 and 8 .

Comment: And if google had answers, I wouldn't have posted the question

Comment: I asked because you did not show any work. Vuforia 7 is not supported. accordingto this thread https://forum.unity.com/threads/black-screen-with-vuforia-when-using-il2cpp-arm64-android.622951/ Android Arm64 is now supported since Vuforia 8.1.7